# И снова тире и двоеточие

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста! В этих двух предложениях просятся дополнительные знаки препинания, но не уверена - правильно ли их здесь ставить.

1) Мы активно сотрудничаем с компаниями по всей России, развиваем отношения и с компаниями из стран СНГ, в основном это Белоруссия и Казахстан.

После СНГ хочется поставить тире - правомерно ли это?

2)Так как мы сотрудничаем с компаниями не только России, но и СНГ, немаловажен, а в некоторых случаях первостепенен, вопрос, касающийся сервиса, мы стараемся сделать покупку у нас максимально удобной и комфортной и постоянно совершенствуем нашу логистическую систему.

После сервиса просится двоеточие.

Answer (score 2):

Тире не нужно. После слова " сервис" нужна точка. Здесь нет никакого пояснения.

Answer (score 0):

После сервиса просится точка. Но фраза все равно очень тяжеловесная.

Answer (score 0):

В первом предложении слова "в основном это Белоруссия и Казахстан" лучше выделить скобками как вставное предложение. Запятая или тире здесь уместны при изменении фразы: "в основном из Белоруссии и Казахстана".
Во втором предложении двоеточие вполне уместно, так как после "сервиса" идет разъяснение того, что понимается под улучшением сервиса. Точка в этом случае разделяет два предложения, две мысли, не связывая их между собой.